# Are 'where to get API' questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, off-topic

According to the help center, resource finding [is off-topic](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

- So shouldn't '[where can I find API for x](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/search?q=where%20API%20is%3Aq)' questions also be off-topic?
- Likewise for '[is there API for x](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%20there%20API%20is%3Aq)'?

Should those posts linked above be [historically locked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) / closed / something else?

Those posts attract promotional/spam answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe these are classic examples of [shopping questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad) and as such should be considered off topic.

It would be my preference to simply close those questions as off topic. Most are old, and therefore possibly outdated.

Comment: It's been 6 days so I'm accepting your answer, how do we go about closing the still-open ones?

Comment: @ymb1 one of two ways, you either go and VtC which will put them on the queue or I/mod go through and modhammer them. I'll do the latter if I get a chance, but need to sort out Monday stuff first.